How to inject a bean when it only in servlet container environment
I need to inject a configuration bean only in the servlet container. So, I used @ConditionalOnBean, but I don't know which bean it should depend on. How can I resolve this?
 @Bean //@ConditionalOnBean(ServletHttpHandlerAdapter.class) public RequestInfoProvider requestInfoProvider() { return new DefaultRequestInfoProvider(); }
There is a RequestInfoProvider interface and I give it a default implement which depend on servlet.
So what i want is when program use servlet container DefaultRequestInfoProvider should be created。
The code doesn't work, it will cause a "bean not found exception"
